# property web builder app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have been working on the Propertywebbuilder app on Heroku.
I am looking for help on how to:

- edit the html, so i can add an item to the footer.
- I would also like to know how i can add more functionality to the app.
  it is built with Ruby on rails.
  here is the link to the app: [PropertywebBuilder](http://propertywebbuilder.com/) 
  I have deployed it on Heroku and have been playing around, but would like to learn how to improve and add things to it.
  many thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should take a Ruby on Rails course. Take a look on YouTube or Udemy. Asking for code isn’t going to work on here.

Comment: Many thanks for that.

Comment: Hi there, creator of PropertyWebBuilder here.   

I'm happy to help you add more functionality.  One thing that will help you get more help on projects like this is to be as specific in your request as possible.  If you say exactly what you want to do, what you have tried, what has gone wrong etc you will get a lot more help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about Rails no one is just going to code for you, unless you're paying them some serious money at least.

The two best resources that helped me learn Ruby on Rails are below.  The first is a free book by Michael Hartl https://www.railstutorial.org/book he also has some screencasts but you have to buy those.

the second resource was a company called the Pragmatic Studio that I actually learned about from reading Hartl's book.  https://pragmaticstudio.com/ they offer a low cost Rails I and Rails II course that is extremely good.  It got me up and building web apps quickly.

Comment: Hi there I have started to learn.